# mac "Hide Tab bar "in menu View

Tags: qt, cocoa, menu, native

I have Qt application moment you add "view" in menu, Hide/show tab bar" gets added and also toggle full screen."
I want to do something when user chose hide/show menu bar. Is there any way to get that event? 
I tried QAbstractNativeEventFilter::nativeEventFilter() but on click on menu item show tab bar this event filter never gets called though it gets called in other operation with "mac_generic_NSEvent"

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask